# How do you turn on a iphone 4 when your power button doesn't work and your phone wont charge?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, battery, charging

This is the second time my phone turns off on full battery and I cant turn it back on last time i waited two days i guess it drained the battery and all but this time my phone was on 30 % I've called apple and they've only sent me to the apple store I NEED my phone. I tried plugging it into the base and pressing the home button and then connecting it to a computer but my phone wont show up as a device and its quite frustrating. can some body please please help me!?

Comment: Honestly, to me it sounds like you are experiencing hardware problems with your phone. You may need to consider replacing it, or having Apple repair it.

Comment: Have you tried holding the Home button for 10 seconds? This has worked for me in the past but can't remember which software/hardware version..

Answer (score 3):

If you plug an iPhone into a charger it should power on. If it's on but frozen, you could connect to iTunes and reset/ wipe it, but that might lose some data depending on your backup situation and what is on the phone.

If it doesn't, then there is a hardware problem and you'll need to get that fixed or live with a faulty device.